# Running .cmd/.bat script in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to write and execute a .cmd script in powershell. The code I have for this is:

```
$script = @'
@echo off
SETLOCAL

CALL something here
'@

Invoke-Expression -Command: $script
```

This is based off [this link](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) which explains the `here string` in powershell. It's at the bottom of the link. Here's [the related msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx).

Here's [another related link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7b398cea-0d29-4588-a6bc-ef793b51cc3c/run-a-dos-command-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) to someone trying to do the same thing.

I keep getting an error that has to do with including the '@' operator within the string:

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:7
+ @echo off
+       ~~~
Unexpected token 'off' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1
+ @echo off
+ ~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@echo' can be used only as an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$echo'.
```

I've tried escaping the '@' symbol, and a plethora of other things. I'd like to know why it seemed to work for them in the third link, but throws this error in my case.

**Edit:**
Writing to a .bat file then running the bat file resulted in the same error:

```
$batchFileContent = @'
@echo off
c:\windows\system32\ntbackup.exe backup "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\NTBackup\data\chameme.bks" /n "1file.bkf1 created 06/09/2013 at 09:36" /d "Set created 06/09/2013 at 09:36" /v:no /r:no /rs:no /hc:off /m normal /j chameme /l:s /f "\\fs1\Exchange Backups$\1file.bkf"
'@

$batchFileContent | Out-File -LiteralPath:"$env:TEMP\backup.cmd" -Force

Invoke-Expression -Command:"$env:TEMP\backup.cmd"

Remove-Item -LiteralPath:"$env:TEMP\backup.cmd" -Force
```

As Bill Stewart pointed out, I should write the content of the .cmd script in powershell.

Edit:
This

```
$script = @'
cmd.exe /C "@echo off"
cmd.exe /C "SETLOCAL"

cmd.exe /C "CALL something here"
'@

Invoke-Expression -Command: $script
```

Seems to work.

Comment: Why do you need to do it? Just do whatever you need to do in PowerShell directly.

Comment: Invoke-Expression will invoke **Powershell** commands. To execute batch commands, save them in a batch file and execute cmd.exe with that file as a parameter. Alternatively you can enter a cmd.exe session within powershell then execute individual commands

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I was so intent on finding a way to run the script, that I didn't think to have powershell do it. At this point I am curious why it wasn't working for me, though I will probably end up using powershell instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `Invoke-Expression` interprets your string with PowerShell. PowerShell allows you to run shell commands, but it interprets things as PowerShell first. The `@` character is the splatting operator in PowerShell.

You should save the commands in a batch file, and then execute that.

Or you can execute single line commands by shelling out to `cmd.exe`:

```
Invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c @echo something"
```